# Conditional ORDER BY not working for temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

For the following simplified T-SQL statement

```
DECLARE @SortColumn nvarchar(50)
SET @SortColumn = 'Price'

SELECT Name, 1+1 as Price
INTO #MyTempTable
FROM Events
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
       WHEN @SortColumn = 'Name' THEN Name 
    END,
    CASE 
       WHEN @SortColumn = 'Price' THEN Price 
    END DESC
```

Why do I get the error:

> Invalid column name 'Price'.

Is it possible to sort on a calculated column?

Note that my actual problem is part of a much more complex query, but this simplified example does demonstrate the problem and will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `order by` a computed field.  You just can't include such a field as an *expression* in the `order by`.  Here is one work-around:

```
SELECT e.Name, v.Price
INTO #MyTempTable
FROM Events e OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES (1 + 1)) v(price)
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @SortColumn = 'Name' THEN e.Name END),
         (CASE WHEN @SortColumn = 'Price' THEN v.Price END DESC);
```

That is, you can define the expressions using `OUTER APPLY`.  Then the result can be used just as if it were a column in a table.

There is basically no limit on defining the expression.  In can include columns from all tables that appear earlier in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Looks promising. So that I can test it, could you help me out with the syntax for multiple computed fields e.g. Price and Profit?

Comment: Regarding my above comments, you just do two OUTER APPLYs

Comment: Dan, you can use two `OUTER APPLY` if one field depends on the other.  Otherwise `(VALUES (1 + 1, 2 + 2)) v(a, b)` will work.